# Binary representation in base (-2) shift left

Tags: algorithm, binary

Given a binary representation of a number x in base (-2), return the binary representation of ceiling(x/2) in base (-2).
Is there a solution in O(1)? I tried to think of a "matching" operation to shift left like you would do if the base was 2 but couldn't find any.

Is there a better way to solve this than to convert x from base (-2) to decimal, then compute ceiling(x/2) and only then find the binary representation in base (-2) to it?

Comment: Hint: `-1 = -2 + 1`. This implies that `(-1)(-2)^k = 1(-2)^k + 1(-2)^{k+1}` etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In base (-2), a number is represented as:

```
x = a[0](-2)^0 + a[1](-2)^1 + a[2](-2)^2 + ...a[k](-2)^k + ...
```

Where the `a[k]` are equal to 0 ou 1. Divide `x` par 2 gives the relation:

```
y = x/2 = -a[1](-2)^0 - a[2](-2)^1  -a[3](-2)^2  ... - a[k+1](-2)^k + ...
        =  b[0](-2)^0 + b[1] (-2)^1 + b[2](-2)^2  ...+ b[k](-2)^k + ...
```

The coefficients `b[k]` are now equal to 0 or -1 instead of 0 or 1.

To convert the result in a suitable base (-2) representation, on have to use the simple relation

```
-1 = -2 + 1
```

This implies that

```
(-1)(-2)^k = 1(-2)^k + 1(-2)^{k+1}
```

Therefore, a simple iterative procedure on the `b[k]` coefficients allows to perform the divison by 2.

This provides a simple O(logn) implementation, iterating over the bits. In the following code,
I used an integer array to represent the base (-2) decomposition. Using an integer instead of an array
with the same algorithm will not change the time efficiency, only reduce the memory used.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

void print (const std::vector<int> &v) {
    for (int i = v.size()-1; i >= 0; --i) {
        std::cout << v[i] << " ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}

//  conversion int -> base (-2)
std::vector<int> int2basem2 (int n) {
    std::vector<int> mbits (32, 0);
    int i = 0;
    int sign = 1;
    while (n != 0) {
        int remainder = n%2;
        if (remainder) {
            mbits[i] = 1;
            n -= sign;
        }
        n /= 2;
        i++;
        sign = -sign;
    }
    return mbits;
}

//  Conversion bas -2 -> int
basem22int (const std::vector<int> &mbits) {
    int n = 0;
    int base = 1;
    int size = mbits.size();
    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
        if (mbits[i]) n += base;
        base *= -2;
    }
    return n;
}

//  division by 2 in base -2
std::vector<int> div2 (const std::vector<int> &in) {
    int size = in.size();
    std::vector<int> div (size, 0);
    int carry_out = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < size-1; ++i) {
        int j = i+1;
        div[i] = carry_out ^ in[j];
        carry_out = !carry_out && in[j];
    }
    div[size-1] = carry_out;
    return div;
}

int main() {
    int n = 1379;
    std::cout << "n = " << n << std::endl;
    auto mbits = int2basem2 (n);
    std::cout << "representation of n in base -2: \t";
    print (mbits);
    mbits = div2(mbits);
    int m = basem22int (mbits);
    std::cout << "representation of n/2 in  base -2: \t";
    print (mbits);
    std::cout << "n/2 = " << m << std::endl;
    
    return 0;
}
```